# Enable timed caching using java

Tags: caching, timed

I have set expires for a particular api using httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", c.getTimeInMillis());
however when i make the api call it does not seem to work. Every time it's making the api call, looks like timed cache is not working. Any help?

Comment: cache-control: no-cache, no-store
connection: close
content-type: application/x-jsend;charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 30 Jul 2018 18:53:00 GMT
expires: Tue, 31 Jul 2018 18:53:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
transfer-encoding: chunked

Comment: This is how my Response Headers look like..i have expires set.